# I confuse between using right article

Tags: articles

Every time, I confuse what I need to use: "a" or "the".

I understood that "a" means something abstract, and "the" is used when we talk about something concrete.
But, this is my case. I need to write a description of the programming method.

```
/**
 * Checks that a connection is established.
 * @return true if a connection exists.
 */
```

In this case, I don't know which article I need to use before "connection" in the first sentence. It must check that connection that belongs to this method is established. So it means that we are talking about (a/the) concrete connection.
But this connection in every running of the program will be different.

Answer (score 2):

The method is a piece of code that has been written and set aside, to be called at any time the main program requires it. It checks for *any connection that might happen to exist*. So when describing what the method does the indefinite article **a** is appropriate:

```
/**
 * Checks that a connection is established.
 * @return true if a connection exists.
 */
bool isConnectionEstablished() {
    #code goes here
}
```

The first time you interact with the method in the main code you are still checking for *any* connection and the indefinite article is still appropriate:

```
#See if there is a connection
bool existsConnection = isConnectionEstablished();
```

If you call the method again, like if the connection drops and you want to see if it has been re-established, you are then dealing with a specific connection (the one that was checked for previously) and you would use the definite article **the**, as I did at the beginning of this sentence:

```
#See if the connection has come back
existsConnection = isConnectionEstablished();
```